# Paste cells into Outlook then convert table to text in Excel

Tags: excel, text, outlook, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to build a macro that grabs a selection of cells from an Excel spreadsheet, pastes the cells into a new outlook email, then changes the format of the cells.

Specifically I want to convert the table to text, then change the font to Arial size 10.

The code below does the above, but I haven't been able to figure out how to convert the table to text, then change the text font.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub Email_test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Sheets("Master").Range("A1:B99").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = "User@company.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Cells as text "
    .HTMLbody = RangetoHTML(rng)

    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.

    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, instead of `HTMLbody` use `body` also removed your range to html function

```
Sub Email_test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = Sheets("Master").Range("A1:B99").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    Dim v As Variant: v = rng.Value
    Dim tempStr As String: tempStr = ""
    For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
            For j = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
                If j = 2 Then
                    tempStr = tempStr & v(i, j) & vbCrLf
                Else
                    tempStr = tempStr & v(i, j) & " "
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = "User@company.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Cells as text "
        .body = tempStr

        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.

        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Please mark as an answer if you are satisfied with reply

Comment: Thank you, that helps.
Only problem is that now I've lost all of the formatting from the Cells.

Comment: You said that you wanted to convert your table to text :) . Did you mean you want to have a borderless table?

Comment: I want to convert table to text, but I want to keep formatting, such as bold and underline in certain areas

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

   You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose.